# Pass a column and table dynamically @Query JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Currently I would like to know how to make a nativeQuery passing by parameter the column and the table for the creation of the query, remaining more or less in this way. Although I don't know if this is possible in JPA:

```
@Query(value = "select :column from :table", nativeQuery=true)
public List<String> getValues(String column, String table);
```

Or is there some other way to do this by sending the two parameters?

Comment: Yes, you can do this by generating the query string dynamically and passing it to an EntityManager.createNativeQuery call directly (JPA directly), but should you?Why would you want to risk letting users query any column on any table in your database? you might as well let them pass in the query string used to query the DB.

Comment: As mentioned above, It is not recommended as you could be a target for SQL injection attack.

Comment: how to do it using EntityManager.createNativeQuery? please help me

Answer (score 0):

on this query, you make your parameters as **Named Parameters**, use the annotation ***@Param(parameter)***.

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, String> 
{
    @Query(value = "select :column from :table", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<String> getValues(@Param("column") String column, @Param("table") String table);
}
```